# Can I name or give an ID to a wellPanel in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app which has two types of well panels depending on what is contained within them, and I would like to set the background of one type to light green, and the other type to light blue. At the moment I do this by setting:

```
tags$head(tags$style(type = 'text/css',".well{background-color: #EFF8CD;}))
wellPanel("My first type of well panel")
```

which gives me the green background for all panels, 
and then using

```
wellPanel(style = "background-color:#c9d7e8;")
```

for the second type of panel.

Is it possible to give these different well panels a name or ID so that I can set the colour in a central place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass named parameters to `wellPanel`, in your case it is better to use a class I think :

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(type = 'text/css',".myclass1 {background-color: #EFF8CD;}"),
    tags$style(type = 'text/css',".myclass2 {background-color: #c9d7e8;}")
  ),
  wellPanel("My first type of well panel", class = "myclass1", id = "myid1"),
  wellPanel("My second type of well panel", class = "myclass2", id = "myid2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm still finding my feet with CSS, so this is very helpful and does exactly what I need it to do (and will clearly come in handy in other situations).